# Delete Certain Files in Folders using Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, ffmpeg, delete-file

I want to delete certain files in my Folder using Powershell.
The Script should be able to differentiate between the filenames and only delete the matching files

The Code I've got so far:

```
Get-ChildItem *.mkv | where BaseName -notlike '*`[HEVC]'| foreach {
ffmpeg -i $_ -c:v libx265 -c:a copy -x265-params crf=25 "$($_.BaseName) [HEVC].mkv" -n
}
```

Note that this is the code to encode the files. After the video is encoded, I want to delete the original file.

I tried using Remove-Item, but I can't figure out how to configure it.
Additionally (this has nothing to do with the deletion of the files), I tried changing this part:

```
 "where BaseName -notlike '*`[HEVC]'" to something like "where BaseName -notlike '*`[HEVC]' or [Date1]`*'"
```

so that it can exclude files with [Date1] and [Time1] at the beginning of the video name, but I can't figure out how to do it, as my PowerShell knowledge is still limited.

Any Answers or tips are appreciated, I'll try to respond as soon as I can.

Comment: What have you tried with Remove-Item? How did it fail? It's pretty straight-forward: `Remove-Item $_.FullName`

Comment: on the conditions you could use `where {$_.BaseName -notlike '*[HEVC]' -and $_.Date -gt <date>}`